# Why does Lily's name (and gender) change?

Tags: comics, cthulhu-mythos, alan-moore, providence

In Providence (by Moore and Burrow), the name of Black's lover changes, in the final pages of his diary, from Lilly to Lily and he refers to them as a **she** rather than a **he**. I read these in Italian so I'm not sure if I missed something in translation.

**Why is this?**

---

n.b. You can see it in the diary pages after **vol. IX: Outsiders**.

[image]

> It occurred to me that it could be a reference to Lilith. Plus we know of a french speaking character in Roulet.

Comment: The reference appears in the UK version. I suspect that your question is more "why does it" than "does it", so I've edited accordingly.

Comment: Well "why does it?" is literary criticism: I have my suspects about it (in the final paragraph of the question). But thanks for confirming from the UK version! Will you provide an answer that I can upvote and accept?

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect the bit that's actually interesting (e.g. *why* does the name change) rather than answering the boring bit (e.g. does it change, yes it does have a scan).

Comment: alan-moore tag was originally present but was removed on the ground of a decision on meta...?

Comment: "*Black despises Prissy even knowing she loves him, apparently considering her intellectually inferior, but it seems to hint some misogyny and the cold and in this case cruel character Russell thought he had. I don’t know if this use of ”their” is accepted but I think it’s a play and hint on the two personalities/lives of Russell, both lost with his death.*" - https://factsprovidence.wordpress.com/moore-lovecraft-comics-annotation-index/providence-1/comment-page-1/